# Как задать тип принимаемого значения для функции (метода)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, типы-данных, типы

Есть функция:

```
def my_sqr(value) -> int:
    pass
```

Нужно, чтобы value была только типа int. В Питоне функция может принимать произвольный тип. Но всё-таки нет ли способа явно указать, что value - это только int? Это нужно, чтобы случайно не вызнать функцию с неверным параметром. Или единственный вариант - делать проверку типа непосредственно внутри функции (имхо, не айс)?

Answer (score 1):

Можно объявить как `def my_sqr(value: int) -> int:`, но в любом случае при вызове никаких проверок не будет (ни на тип параметра, ни на тип возвращаемого значения). Python - это язык с динамической типизацией, использование аннотаций типов не добавляет проверок, выполняемых во время исполнения программы.

Аннотации типов (см. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) работают только со сторонними инструментами (например, PyCharm проверяет что вы пытаетесь передать в функцию и может подчеркнуть как ошибку).

Если у вас функция используется только внутри вашего кода, то достаточно аннотаций типа и проверки в PyCharm или с помощью [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) (инструмент статической проверки типов в программах на Python согласно PEP 484). Если у вас модуль, и функция может вызываться сторонним кодом, то лучше добавить явные проверки внутри функции.

Comment: лучше не пытаться писать <вставьте ваш любимый статический язык здесь> используя синтаксис Питона (динамический язык). В разных языках свои соглашения и принятые способы решения одних и тех же задач¶ В качестве *дополнения* к существующим тестам (не замена), можно аннотацию добавить. Можно думать об аннотации как способ декларативно семейство тестов создавать (как и любые другие тесты -- больше не всегда лучше и наличие тестов не гарантирует корректную работу)¶ Для проверки во время исполнения, можно декоратор добавить, который выбросит TypeError, если необходимо -- но подобные вещи ещё реже..

Comment: ..стоит применять чем аннотацию

Comment: @jfs, mypy - это не "мой любимый язык", это по сути инструмент статической проверки аннотаций типов в коде на Python, разрабатываемый в том числе Гвидо ван Россумом.

Comment: Если приходится объяснять анекдот, значит это плохой анекдот (для данной аудитории): представьте  человек писал на Java всю жизнь. Потом решил Python выучить, но привычки остались, которые ведут к вопросам "как мне статическую проверку типов добавить" -- то есть человек пытается продолжить писать Java код, только используя Питон синтаксис. На место Java подставьте ваш любимый статический язык¶ А про mypy я ничего не говорил (тем более что он у вас явно в ответе упомянут—не надо меня так оскорблять—вы думаете я ответ из двух коротких параграфов не стал читать прежде чем комментарий писать?

Comment: Ну сорри, я вас не так понял. P.S. вот по поводу того что не стоит пытаться применять статическую типизацию в языке программирования, в которой ее нет, может ответ напишите?

Comment: я не говорил, что *никогда* не следует использовать type annotation. Просто следует быть осторожным, чтобы не злоупотреблять¶ Если вам нужно многомиллионную кодовую базу рефакторить (по любой причине, к примеру, перевести часть на Питон 3), я бы начал с написания огромного количества тестов, чтобы убедиться, что изменения не сломали код (по крайней мере те случаи, которые нам интересны). static проверка типов это всего лишь одно (и IMO не самое важное) семейство тестов. Самые разные тесты бывают полезными -- иногда полезно рубильник в data center дёрнуть  и посмотреть как система отреагирует.

Answer (score 1):

Python язык с динамической системой типов и по этой причини полиморфизм в нем везде. Единственны способ проверки это явно проверить тип агрумента с помощью функции type, но по большей части в этом нет смысла. В случае если при выполнении произойдет ошибка сам интерпретатор гинерирует исключение, которое можно будет обработать. Фактически при проверке типа вы искусственено ограничиваете функционал. При программировании функций необходимо полагаться на поддерживаемые объектами интерфейсы, а не на их типы. Например функция:

```
def fn(arg1, arg2): return arg1 + arg2
```

может правильно работать в том случае если оба аргумента являются числами или  строками поскольку и у чисел и у строк выполнена перегрузка оператора "+". А если проверять тип аргумента заранее то она сможет работать только с числами и ее возможности будут искусственно ограниченны.

Comment: Тогда как объяснить вот это? https://ideone.com/Xj0hNr