# Использование аннотаций в коде Python

Tags: python, python-3.6, комментарии, аннотации

Недавно прочитал статью по поводу нововведения - аннотаций в [Python 3.6 (src)](https://dzone.com/articles/new-in-python-syntax-for-variable-annotations) из [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/).

**Само нововведение состоит из:**

- ввод: `name: str = 'Dmytro'`
- вывод: `%file_name%.__annotations__`
- не является инициатором переменной `age: str = 1`
- может аннотировать переменную без значения `und: str # как-то так`
- не является типом переменной (показывает ошибку типа, но выполняет код)

Так вот, исходя из этого нововведения решил поинтересоваться:

1. Какие применения данной функции вы видите?
2. Как на практике это может помочь в написании кода?

Свои маленькие выводы уже сделал, хотел бы услышать сообщество..
*PS: Я новичек в Python и хочу идти в ногу со временем понимая зачем мне может пригодится новый функционал.*

Comment: Эти аннотации нужны для упрощения понимания кода, бонусом может быть проверка типа (IDE может подсказать, что значение не соответствует типу). Подобное было сделано для описания типов параметров функций и возвращаемых значений, например: `def get_value(num: int) -> str: return "a" * num`

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Указание типа переменной в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775151/Указание-типа-переменной-в-python), [Как задать тип принимаемого значения для функции (метода) Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799525/Как-задать-тип-принимаемого-значения-для-функции-метода-python-3)